# How can I qualify an autowired property with a variable

Tags: spring, autowired

I am working on a Spring application and for one of my scenarios, I had to write two implementations of a Service class. I would like to know how to autowire this in a service layer based on service id at runtime.

```
@Autowired
ProductPricing accessProduct; 

public static void main(String args[])
{
 long productId = serviceDao.getService(site.getSiteID()).getServiceId();

 accessProduct.calculatePrice(pricingParam)
}

public class PricingManager1 implements ProductPricing
{
   public void calculatePrice(Parmeter pricingParam) {}
}

public class PricingManager2 implements ProductPricing
{
   public void calculatePrice(Parmeter pricingParam) {}
}
```

Now depending on the productId, either the method on PricingManager1  or PricingManager2 will be called. How to achieve the same dynamically? If I autowire the Service classes with qualifier,  is there any way we can pass runtime productId as qulifier in main class?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected output by using `@Service` and then getting the bean from spring `context` object in your `main()` as shown below:

**Service Classes:**

```
@Service("pricingManager1")
public class PricingManager1 implements ProductPricing
{
   public void calculatePrice(Parmeter pricingParam) {}
}

@Service("pricingManager1")
public class PricingManager2 implements ProductPricing
{
   public void calculatePrice(Parmeter pricingParam) {}
}
```

**Main Class:**

```
//No Autowiring
public static void main(String args[])
{
 long productId = serviceDao.getService(site.getSiteID()).getServiceId();

 //get the spring context object

 //get the bean from context
 if(productId == condition) {

    beanContext.getBean("pricingManager1").calculatePrice(pricingParam)
 } else {
    beanContext.getBean("pricingManager2").calculatePrice(pricingParam)
 }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks...but is there any way to achieve the same via variable autowiring?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring **Boot**, you can achieve this by using **@ConditionalOnExpression** annotation and **SpEL** along with **@Bean**.

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{this.productId == 999}")
```

If you are **not** using Spring Boot, use **@Conditional** from Spring **4**, but this will need more effort to get the same result.